# Service Discovery vs Service Proxy Vertx

Tags: java, vert.x, service-discovery

I am new to `vertx` and `microservice` based architecture. I am trying to understand the difference between `service discovery` and `service proxy`.
I understand that `service discovery` publishes resources to discover but what is the role of `service proxy`?

Answer (score 1):

[Vert.x Service Proxy](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-service-proxy/java/) is a Vert.x module that allows to invoke a remote service on the Vert.x EventBus.

A service is described with a Java interface containing methods following the async pattern. Under the hood, messages are sent on the event bus to invoke the service and get the response back. But for ease of use, the module generates a proxy that you can invoke directly (using the API from the service interface).

Answer (score 0):

> It lets you expose a service on the event bus, so, any other Vert.x
> component can consume it, as soon as they know the address on which
> the service is published.

From the [documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-service-proxy/java/).

One of its main aim is to reduce boilerplate code when creating a service and simply using annotations.